# Intermittent fail on jQuery each loop with ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to debug a problem with an `ajax` loop which is giving intermittent errors.  Specifically, I am looping through 20 records and inserting them into a database, but sometimes only 17 of 20 records are inserted, sometimes 18 of 20, etc.  Here is the code:

```
function myInsertLoop(){
  $('input[name=r_maybe].r_box').each(function(){
    if( $(this).prop('checked') ){ 
      var rn = $(this).prop('value');   
      $.ajax({
        url: sURL + 'myController/Insert',
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {'rn': rn},
        error:          
        function(data) {alert('Error:'+rn+'\n\n'+data);}
      });
    } 
  });   
}
```

When I repeat the process using the same data, I get a different few rows that do not insert.  I can alert the value of `rn`, which tells me which record(s) threw the error, but I still don't know why the error occurs.  The data and datatypes of the inserted records are all consistent, so I don't believe that is what is throwing the error.  I'm guessing the error has something to do with timing, but not sure.

I tried to alert the `data` callback, but the only thing I see is `[object Object]`.

[image: object Object]

Any ideas on what I should be looking for here? What could be the reason for the intermittent failures to insert?  Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `alert`, use `console.log` and look in the console, then you can actually see what's in `data`. Without that it is tough to answer this.

Comment: I don't see why this would be a problem, but try throttling your requests (instead of sending them in a tight loop, use `setTimeout` to only send one every 100 MS or so

Comment: Good ideas.  I will try both of these now and see how it goes.

Comment: Wow.  How silly of my to be trying to debug this using `alert`.  Now that You've got me using `console.log` I can totally see what is going on and have the ability to dig deeper and find the true cause of the error.  I will get this figured out, but right now I need some sleep.  Thanks for your help.   I will also try and experiment with using `setTimeout` to slow things down a bit.  Thanks again.